# How to generate Sub Report in Crystal Reports using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am new for ASP.NET MVC generating Sub report in Crystal report. Kindly give any suggestion.

Here I am attached for my coding for generating Crystal Report in ASP.NET MVC. But I need to generate Subreport in Crystal Report.

Below on my Single Report generation coding, where I am adding only tollgate datatable, but I need to add more than one datatable inside of setdatasource.

```
public ActionResult EmployeeExpensesReport( )
{

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=192.168.0.73\SQLEXPRESS,14330;initial catalog=WafeERP_NEW;user id=sa;password=wafewin;");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from view_TollGate", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adp.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            ReportClass RC = new ReportClass();
            RC.FileName = Server.MapPath("rpt_EmployeeExpensesReport.rpt");
            RC.Load();
            RC.SetDataSource(dt);
            Stream stream = RC.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: You should considering updating your question with relevant codes and analysis done on the subject. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to ask question. This otherwise will attract many down votes...

Comment: @Aditya: Here i am updating my coding for generating single report using asp.net mvc , but i need to generate subreport in main report kindly give ur support

Answer (score 0):

You don't "generate a sub-report in MVC", you design your main report to include a sub-report bound to the sections of your dataset that may form a hierarchical structure.

Think of xml with an element with sub-elements. The sub report would be bound to these sub-elements. This is done in the Crystal designer then it will show the sub-report in ASP.NET

Comment: I am designed main report to include a sub report , but now my issues are how to bind the multiple dataset in a singldatasource
Like this " RC.SetDataSource(dt);" If u have any tutorials or link send me